# Looking for documentation on entry points for avifil32.dll

Tags: c#, dll, msdn, entry-point

I have seen some examples of people using avifil32.dll to read / write AVI files and the DLL is supplied in Windows XP (possibly not Vista / Win 7). However even though its used in an example for the extern keyword of C# on MSDN I can't find any documentation on it there.

Where can I find a list of functions or entry points into avifil32.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find that at [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/).